# Squashing function from $\mathbb{R}_+$ , not $\mathbb{R}$?

Tags: probability, analysis

I know of sigmoid functions that map $\mathbb{R}$ to $[0, 1]$. But what functions map only $\mathbb{R}_+$ to $[0, 1]$? One example I can think of is the family of functions of the form $$f(x) = \frac{x^n}{x^n+k}$$

where $n, k > 0$. But I'm not sure if other examples exist - do they?

Comment: How particular are you about endpoints? You could easily gin up an $\arctan$ function that maps $\mathbb{R}_+$ to $(0,1).$

Comment: Any Cumulative distribution Function of a [positive continuous random variable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_probability_distributions#Supported_on_semi-infinite_intervals,_usually_[0,%E2%88%9E)) may meet your requirements

Answer (score 1):

If you are happy with the way sigmoid functions map $\Bbb R$ to $[0,1]$, then you also ought to be happy with how they map $\Bbb R^+$ to $[0,1]$ without any further modifications. A sigmoid function never becomes exactly $0$ or $1$, so it's not onto in any case.

If you want a function $\Bbb R^+\to [0,1]$ that is as close to onto as a sigmoid function is to being an onto function $\Bbb R\to [0,1]$, then one way is to compose functions. For instance, logarithms are bijections from $\Bbb R^+\to \Bbb R$, so taking a positive number, then first applying a logarithm and then a sigmoid will give you a map $\Bbb R^+\to [0,1]$ that only misses $0$ and $1$, and hits every number in-between.

As to your question of whether other examples exist, they do, and there are *many* of them. You can use the cotangent function (properly scaled) or the error function instead of the sigmoid function, for instance. You can use something like $x - \frac1x$ instead of the logarithm. There are plenty of changes you could do to make other examples.

And beyond these, there are *countless* other examples, most of which will never be describable in any meaningful way by human civilization.

Comment: Note that the logarithm followed by the sigmoid function is just $x \mapsto \frac{x}{x+1}$, which is a simple description (and it is a special case of the form suggested by OP). Edit: I guess this depends on whether or not you refer to the logistic mapping as "the sigmoid" or reserve the word "sigmoid" for a wider class of functions. :-)

Answer (score 0):

There are tons of options. Here are a few practical examples.
\begin{align*}
f(x)&=\begin{cases}x,&0<x\le 1\\1,&1<x. \end{cases}\\
g(x)&=\frac{\arctan(x-k)}{\pi}+\frac12,
\end{align*}
where $k$ is taken sufficiently large for your purposes.

You need to examine your requirements carefully. If you need a differentiable function, then $f$ will not work. If you need values of the function arbitrarily close to $0,$ then $g$ will not work (unless you're allowed to change your function whenever you want). As mentioned, you have the sigmoid functions, and the ones you've mentioned. Without more context, it's going to be difficult to answer your question. Do you need your function to fit some pre-existing data?